# How can I plot the variation of the value of each input layer with the epoch number in Keras?

Tags: python, keras

I have a `Sequential` ANN, created in Keras. It was created and compiled using the following code:

```
    model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Dense(13, activation='elu', input_shape=[6,]),
    layers.BatchNormalization(),
    layers.Dense(1, activation='linear')])
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
```

I want to be able to plot the variation of the value of each of the 6 inputs, with the epoch number. I know that I need to use `model.layers[0].get_weights()[0]` , but I don't know how to put things together.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define a custom callback `InputLayerValuesCallback` that captures the input layer values at the end of each epoch by calling `model.layers[0].get_weights()[0]`. The input values are stored in the input_values attribute of the callback.

During training, this custom callback is passed to the fit() method using the callbacks parameter. The on_epoch_end() method of the callback is then invoked by the training process at the end of each epoch, allowing the input layer values to be collected.

This is simply an example, and you will need to customize and adapt both the test and train variables, as well as the input values and callback, to suit your specific use case.

```
class InputLayerValuesCallback(Callback):
    def __init__(self):
        super(InputLayerValuesCallback, self).__init__()
        self.input_values = []

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        # Get input layer values
        input_values = self.model.layers[0].get_weights()[0].flatten()
        self.input_values.append(input_values)

model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Dense(13, activation='elu', input_shape=[6,]),
    layers.BatchNormalization(),
    layers.Dense(1, activation='linear')
])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

# Create an instance of the custom callback
input_values_callback = InputLayerValuesCallback()

# Train the model with the callback
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, callbacks=[input_values_callback])

# Convert input values to numpy array for plotting
input_values = np.array(input_values_callback.input_values)

num_inputs = input_values.shape[1]
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=num_inputs, ncols=1, figsize=(8, 6))
```